# grails 2.5.4 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask error creating bean 'pluginManager'

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, grails

Creating new Grails 2.5.4 project. Running the following plugins:

```
Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:

asset-pipeline      2.5.7            --  Asset Pipeline Plugin
cache               1.1.8            --  Cache Plugin
database-migration  1.4.0            --  Grails Database Migration Plugin
geoip               0.3.2            --  Grails GeoIP Plugin
hibernate4          4.3.5.5          --  Hibernate 4 for Grails
jquery              1.11.1           --  jQuery for Grails
jquery-mobile       1.1.0.5          --  Plugin jQuery mobile framework resource files
mail                1.0.7            --  Provides Mail support to a running Grails application
resources           1.2.14           --  Resources
scaffolding         2.1.2            --  Grails Scaffolding Plugin
shared-domain-plugin-upgrade0.1              --  Shared Domain Plugin Upgrade Plugin
shiro               1.2.1            --  Apache Shiro Integration for Grails
spring-mobile       1.1.3            --  Spring Mobile Plugin
tomcat              7.0.55.3         --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webflow             2.1.0            --  Spring Web Flow Plugin
webxml              1.4.1            --  WebXmlConfig
```

When I execute 'grails run-app' getting the following stacktrace error:

```
| Running Grails application
| Error 2018-10-10 14:41:11,073 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1149 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ExceptionInInitializerError: null
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1149 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: java.lang.String
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1149 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2018-10-10 14:41:11,137 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicati
onContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1149 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ExceptionInInitializerError: null
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1149 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: java.lang.String
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1149 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

What should I do to correct?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: From BuildConfig.groovy I'm calling a local plugin which houses all our domain classes 

`grails.plugin.location."shared-domain-plugin" = "../SharedDomainPlugin_254"` 

With Grails Configuration Holder being deprecated, I used the newer injection method within my classes 

`def grailsApplication` 

Within these domain classes I'm am using Database mapping. 
I believe the error is coming from the following code line(s): 

`static mapping = { table (name:'custmast',schema:grailsApplication.config.accounting.schema)`

Comment: referencing variables in Datasource.groovy

`dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
inventory.schema = 'I99FILES'
accounting.schema = 'R99FILES'
orderentry.schema = 'O99FILES'
varsity.schema = 'VARFILES'
purchasing.schema = 'U99FILES'
rita.schema = 'O99FILES'
warranty.schema = 'W99FILES'
environments {`